# Выбор версии NET.Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Язык C#.
Существует ли в Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 возможность выбора под какую конкретно версию NET.Framework разрабатывать программу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В меню студии - Project -> MyProj Properties -> Application -> Target Framework.

Там будет список профилей для клиента, у меня видно от 2 до 4 (2, 3, 3.5, 4).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, позволяет. Для Visual C# Express (русская версия).

1. Зайти в Проект - Свойства.
2. Выбрать в выпадающем меню "Требуемая версия .NET Framework" нужное.

Answer (score 0):

Да, существует, а, если более ранние версии не выбираются, значит нужно доставить [framework 3.5 sp1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/ru-ru/details.aspx?familyid=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=ru)